# Как создать проект в AndroidStudio с api 10?

Tags: android-studio

Нужно создать приложение для версии Android 2.3.3, но при создании нового проекта, минимальная версия Android 4 (api 14).

SDK для версии Android 2.3.3 установлен и вроде недавно у меня была такая возможность, но после обновления пропала.
Можно ли это обойти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, с некоторых пор при создании проекта студия не предлагает минимальный API ниже 14, мотивируя это тем, что уже API 15 покрывает 100% устройств.

Вы можете указать меньшее API после создания проекта: в build.gradle уровня модуля укажите для minSDKversion нужное вам значение

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

или через GUI студии: Project Structure - <ваш модуль> в списке слева - вкладка: Flavors - minSDKversion (введите с клавиатуры нужное API).

Так же вы должны учитывать, что библиотеки поддержки Google в своем большинстве работают с API 14 и выше, то есть вам придется отказаться от большинства из них.

Comment: попробовал, появляется следующее сообщение: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2. В блоке dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

Comment: @kaaa я специально написал, что большинство библиотек не работают на API10, с этим вы ничего не можете сделать на уровне IDE. Либо отказаться от библиотек, либо писать свою реализацию, либо повышать API до 14

Comment: Я понимаю про библиотеки, они мне и не нужны, только простые, но не удается даже с пустым активити запустить. Делаю новый проект, заготовку, меняю миним api и на этом все. Дальше не компилится.

Comment: у меня очень простое приложение, но позволяющее использовать старые мобильники для примитивных задач.

Comment: если вам не нужны библиотеки - удалите их из зависимостей. у вас явно написано, что вы используете AppCompat

Comment: Получилось. Пришлось вручную найти и все вычистить. Благодарю.