# Android Studio 3.1 и API 7

Tags: android-studio

Необходимо создать приложение на версию Android 2.1, однако в Android Studio минимально возможная при создании проекта - 4.0

Comment: зайдите в SDK Manager, поставьте версию Android 2.1 и пробуйте дальше

Comment: Все что ниже 4.0 устарело, а их численность не большая, меньше 1% от всех устройств

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать проект в AndroidStudio с api 10?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817891/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-androidstudio-%d1%81-api-10)